# Error code (exit code 1) when installing netfilterqueue on macOS

Tags: macos, pip

When I try to install the module netfilterqueue for python via pip, I get the error:

> "Command
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>   -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/tmp/pip-install-Ut3XcJ/netfilterqueue/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /private/tmp/pip-record-teUDXs/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-Ut3XcJ/netfilterqueue/"

I installed the module scapy without any problems, so I'm confused why netfilterqueue isn't installing.  I'm currently using macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to these issue on [their Github page](https://github.com/kti/python-netfilterqueue), it is not supported on macOS.

https://github.com/kti/python-netfilterqueue/issues/14:

> [libnetfilterqueue](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/) is a Linux-only feature, so you won't be able to
>   install python-netfilterqueue on Mac OS.

https://github.com/kti/python-netfilterqueue/issues/2:

> Sorry, python-netfilterqueue will not work on Mac because nfqueue is Linux-only: http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/index.html

Answer (score 0):

error code 1 means operation not permitted, so it is a problem of authorization.
Try with sudo before the command:
sudo pip install python-netfilterqueue